# Is any way to add jQuery css on dynamic div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what i have

```
$('.ex3').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() - 300 });
$(window).resize(function() {
$('.ex3').css({ height: $(window).innerHeight() - 300 });
});
```

and my html code

```
<div id="inner-order-details">
<div class="ex3"></div>
</div>
```

Now when i want show dynamic html code below by js works perfect

```
var customerOrder = "test test test";
$('#inner-order-details').html(customerOrder);
```

Now i would like remove `<div class="ex3"></div>` from html and put this dynamic so my html code should be like this

```
<div id="inner-order-details"></div>
```

and my js

```
var customerOrder = "<div class="ex3">test test test</div>";
$('#inner-order-details').html(customerOrder);
```

but when i do that js function not working. How can i add js.css to dynamic div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"<div class="ex3">test test test</div>";
```

Your quotes is the problem, you can replace that line with:

```
"<div class='ex3'>test test test</div>";
```